# Salesforce pull listviews fail for some listviews

Tags: salesforce

Pulling Listviews from salesforce through following url:

```
https://na23.salesforce.com/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Contact/listviews/sfid/results
```

where `sfid` in url is our listview id, and that was working fine for a while, and it still working fine now but not for all lists some of them give us error:

```
[
 {
    "message": "\nDate_of_Next_Outreach__c <= TODAY AND NOT Comm_Plan__c like '%Completed%'\n  ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:475\nunexpected token: 'NOT'",
    "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"
 }
]
```

without any reasons, it just weired as it works for some and not for others?